# Reverting a forced push

Tags: git

I had a feature branch called "feat" that was many commits ahead of master, and a master branch that was ahead of feat.

I issued a fabric script that accidentally issued the command:

```
git push -f origin feat:master
```

This force updated the master with the branch.  Now, master looks like it has been completely overwritten by the branch.

How can I roll this back?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did something else.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1909186, if you found another solution you can answer your own question and accept that answer. Your experience may help others in the future.